# Are words cognate with "Herr" typically associated with men?

Tags: meaning

In distinguishing between *Herren* and *Damen*, I would have guessed that that *Herren* would be for men, because it’s similar to *Herr*, which is one of the few German words I know.

I know that *Damen* is cognate with the English word *dame*, from the etymology information in the [German edition of Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dame) on both the German and English words *Dame*.

But looking at the Wiktionary entry on [Herr](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herr), it mentions a feminine gender word [Herrin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herrin#German), meaning *Lady*. Is this more of a rare exception than the rule? Or is it unsafe to assume that words cognate with *Herr* are typically referring to men?

Comment: On a side note, do not take *Herrin* to mean *lady* or even *Lady* … when the word is used alone, the first associations often include leather and a whip.

Comment: @Jan that's the kind of detail textbooks and dictionaries often don't mention! (The same would be true in English for "mistress")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases a noun describing something male (sex, not gender) has a matching female noun formed by attaching *-in* (and dumping final vowels).

Typical examples are professions and sometimes animals (unless separate male/female words exist) :

- Bäcker -> Bäckerin
- Kellner -> Kellnerin
- Arzt -> Ärztin (note the umlaut!)
- Hase -> Häsin (again *a* shifts to *ä*, *e* is removed)
- Esel -> Eselin

So back to your *Herr -> Herrin* question:

Whenever a pair of male/female form exists, you may assume that the female form is derrived from the male, which is in most cases both the explicitly male and the "neutral" or "generic" term.<sup>1</sup>

Therefore, yes, if a word is derrived from *Herr* it is either male or generic. But please note that you would typically be dealing with *Herr* in the sense of *lord* or *superior*. The standard form of address *Herr* is a honorific that has been "demoted" to a common word.

---

<sup>1</sup>  This is a generalization for beginners, not a fixed rule. I'm sure there are some exceptions.

Comment: "In some cases a noun describing something male (sex, not gender) has a matching female noun" - I think the explanation might be even better without the restriction to "some cases". The suffix "-in" is indeed a very general marker, and - given a suitable context - can be appended to any word. As an example: When telling a fantasy/children's tale about speaking potatoes, the word "Kartoffelin" will invariably be understood to refer to a female potato character by native speakers, simply based on the suffix, even though the word "Kartoffelin" would never appear in any other context.

Comment: As for the footnote: Braut/Bräutigam comes to mind.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: But I wanted to make clear that not all "male" terms have a feminine "-in" counterpart you would find in a dictionary. Obviously you can make up such terms, but keeping  the abuse of these "femininized" (is that a word?) terms in the wake of he feminist movement in mind I hesitate to give a general recommendation. "Taschenrechnerinnen"anyone? (Disclaimer: I am female)

Comment: Again, in an appropriate context, Taschenrechner and Taschenrechnerin might be a happy couple ;) However, I suspect I tried to imagine the explanation into the opposite direction than you're going - I rather tried pointing out that the suffix "-in" will be understood as being a female counterpart of another word by German speakers, not because the word ending on "-in" is listed as something female in a dictionary, but explicitly because of the suffix. In other words, even "-in"-words that are *not* in a dictionary will be understood to be female counterparts of matching "male" terms.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: And if we leave these comments here, I guess OP should really get a good idea on how the mechanism works. Thanks!

Comment: Your theory is wrong. "Bäcker, Kellner, Arzt" as male words don't describe male persons, but the profession in general. To clarify, that you're speaking about men exclusively, you need to add that information in the context or by specifying them explicitly as male.  The same is true for the rare occasions of female general forms like 'Person' or the third language gender, as in 'das Mitglied'. You have to say 'Die weibliche Person hat einen Apfel geklaut' - the famale nature of that person doesn't follow from the gender of the word.

Answer (score 2):

Herr Müller und Herr Maier bezeichnen in der Tat immer Männer, aber es gibt daneben auch die Bedeutung des Herrn wie im berühmten, dialektischen Gegensatz von Herr und Knecht (Hegel), und da ist es die Funktion eines Herrschers, nicht unbedingt eines politischen Herrschers, sondern auch Großgrundbesitzer usw. - da ist das Geschlecht der Person nicht festgelegt, wenn auch das Geschlecht des Wortes männlich ist.

Andere Verwendungen: "Ärzte: Herren über Leben und Tod?", "Hund und Herrchen", "Domina Dolores: Lass mich Deine Herrin sein!".

Comment: Andrew mentioned that he knows only a few German words, I fear that most of those that you have used are not among them ;)

Comment: Wo hat Andrew das erwähnt? Ich seh's nicht.

Comment: @userunknown *which is one of the few German words I know*, erster Absatz, letzter Teilsatz.

Comment: Stimmt. Andererseits ist man gehalten nur Fragen zu stellen, die eine größere Audienz interessieren.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did my German surname make you think I was proficient in German?

Comment: No, I didn't look at your name,  I tend to answer all questions in German, because that is how you learn foreign languages: practice.